# Remmina pre and post VNC connection commands

Tags: ssh, vnc, remmina

There is little documentation on if this can be achieved. My workflow is thus: I connect to my remote machine via SSH, then if I need a GUI, launch TigerVNC server using

```
/usr/bin/vncserver :4 -geometry 1920x1080 -depth 32 -nolisten tcp -localhost
```

(saved conveniently to a bash alias). Then I can connect to it using Remmina as usual. I never bothered to tinker with the pre and post connection commands in Remmina connection editor. Today, suddenly, I noticed them and wondered if I could issue my VNC server spawning commands through there. So I copied the above into the pre-connection box, and tried to connect. No luck. Then I used my bash alias. No luck.

Finally I created an executable shell file with that command, and provided that file in the pre-connection field. This is similar to what [the Wiki has](https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/wiki/Remmina-User's-guide). Now it is just stuck at the "Connecting to Host" dialogue box. I cannot tell if I am getting closer. Unfortunately, the Wiki does not elaborate on that, or I am too blind to effectively search for it. Can anyone help? Is this even possible? I would be great if Remmina could connect via SSH, spawn a VNC server, and then connect to GUI, all in one shot.

---

Obviously, I am also interested in the post-command to `/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! I figured it out! The command is run on the client machine, not the server. Therefore,

```
/usr/bin/ssh user@host '/usr/bin/vncserver :4 -geometry 1920x1080 -depth 32 -nolisten tcp -localhost'
```

in the pre command, and

```
/usr/bin/ssh user@host '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :4'
```

in the post command does exactly what I want! Remmina is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

(An alternative way using [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) server)

Pre-command:

```
sh -c '( ssh user@host '\''killall x11vnc ; x11vnc -forever -passwd SOMEPASSWORD -display :0'\'' & ) ; sleep 5'
```

Post-command:

```
ssh user@host 'killall x11vnc'
```

Explanations:

- pre-command does the following:

  - starts a background ssh process which (on the remote side):

    - terminates any running x11vnc servers
    - starts x11vnc server
  - waits 5 seconds for this background process to setup VNC server (to prevent remmina from connecting too early)
- post-command terminates all x11vnc servers on the remote side